# How to pass 1 variable from 1 php to another php : error

Tags: php

I am trying to save the table name as a variable in 1 php file and then using that variable in another php file to fire queries. But it is not working. I dont know if it is possible or not.

What Exactly I want : User will input a name. "newtablephp.php" will create a table with that name and save the table name in some vairable. Now "enterdataphp.php" should be able to use that vairable inorder to update the rows of the table.

This is required since each day, a new table will be created for data record with different names and will be saved in .csv format.

newtablephp.php

```
     <?php

    include 'connectornewtable.php';


    $val1 = $_POST['ntable'];
    $val2 = $_POST['day'];


    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $val1 as SELECT * FROM $val2";

    echo $val1;


    if(!mysql_query($sql))
    {
    die('Error: '.mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

enterdataphp.php

```
    <?php
    include 'connectornewtable.php';
    include 'newtablephp.php';

    $val3=$_POST['time'];
    $val4=$_POST['name'];
    $val5=$_POST['student'];

    $sqlupdate1="UPDATE $val1 SET `Teacher'=$val4,`Student`=$val5 WHERE `Time`=$val3";

    if(!mysql_query($sqlupdate1))
    {
    die('Error: '.mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

the val1 stores the input name of table. I want to use this val1 in enterdataphp.php

Thank you

Comment: you can use the session

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: sure. I will...it is my first project, so I dint know. will keep this in mind and modify it asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store $val1 value in session variable as:

```
 $_SESSION['val']=$val1;
```

and retrive this value on enterdataphp.php

as

```
$variable=$_SESSION['val'];
```

and you must start session on this page

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the name in a table that you create for this.
Or you can pass it to enterdataphp.php?name=$val1 by refreshing the iframe where enterdata is loaded

Answer (score 0):

```
$val1 = $_POST['ntable'];
$_SESSION['val1']=$val1;
```

don't forget to use `session_start()` in top of your page

and use it where ever you want.